# Handling textview hit bottom in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm setting a message in a simple alert dialog. I need to know if the user has read all the text inside the dialog or not. Is there any way to set a scroll listener or something in an alert dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom dialog and then set some listener to your custom View. Here's a good example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713501